# Possible to change the SASS/Compass output folder for different files?

Tags: css, haml, sass, compass-sass

I'm wondering if it's possible for Compass to output files to different directories? I have a fairly large project and while most CSS files go in the /css folder, others need to go in the /admin/css folder. I'm symlinking them for now, but it'd be great if I could define an array of files (in config.rb?) that could be output elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In config.rb edit the `css_dir = "/"` to your wanted directory! I don't think it can handle multiple output folders.

Answer (score 1):

One way around it might be to set up symlinks from where they're supposed to go to the actual output CSS files.

I might be doing the same myself for a Magento package with different themes.